# PreferenceFragment theme has big text?

Tags: android, themes, android-preferences, android-theme, preferencefragment

So I switched to 
`import android.support.v14.preference.PreferenceFragment;` and noticed that I have to set a Preference theme. So I did this in my `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14</item>
</style>
```

However now the text in my settings / preference menu is huge (specifically, the headers). How can I get it to be a more reasonable size like it originally was when I wasn't using the non-support-library version of `PreferenceFragment`?

From my gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.somepackagename.amyapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:23.2.1'
}
```

Updated to

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.somepackagename.amyapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:25.2.0'
}
```

Comment: What version of the Support Library are you using? The latest (25.2.0)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Looks like 
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:23.2.1' ? If I use 25 I get some API error

Comment: You're trying a version 13 versions behind what is available now. Change your compileSdkVersion to 25 and try with the latest.

Comment: I updated the post with my thing. If I change to 25 do I have to change everything else?

Comment: You should always use only a single version of the Support Library, yep.

Comment: How do I know what to change everything else to? buildtools, import versions, etc?

Comment: The latest of everything? Android Studio offers quick help for updating to the latest versions (yellow text over each one saying 'a newer version of this is available').

Comment: I updated everything to version 25, but still the same problem